# JavaScript split function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have this JS function:

```
<p class="price text-center ng-binding" total-price="">€ 0.44</p>
<script>
    function (){
        var value = document.getElementByClassName("price text-center ng-binding").innerText;
        var splited = value.split(" ");
        var conversionValue = splited[1];
        return conversionValue;
    }
</script>
```

I want to split "€ 0.44" in two parts: "€ " and "0.44".

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There is no `getElementByClassName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `getElementByClassName()` isn't a function it should be `getElementsByClassName()` note the `s` at the end of `element`.

You could not call `innerText` on `getElementsByClassName()` since the function return an array of elements, instead try to select the first occurrence like :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("price text-center ng-binding")[0].innerText;
```

I suggest the use of `.querySelector()` in your case since it will target the element directly, like :

```
document.querySelector('.price.text-center.ng-binding').innerText;
```

**NOTE :** You need to give you function a some name.

```js
var value = document.querySelector('.price.text-center.ng-binding').innerText;
var splited = value.split(" ");
var conversionValue = splited[1];

console.log(conversionValue);
```

```html
<p class="price text-center ng-binding" total-price="">
  € 0.44
</p>
```

Comment: Hmm, turns out `innerText` strips leading / trailing whitespace. Good answer